# How to access Google Drive from the command line using shell in ChromeOS?

Tags: command-line, chrome, chromium-os, google-drive

Is it possible to have command-line access to Google Drive from the crosh shell? Conceivably, something like:

cd ~/'Google Drive'

In my current environment Developer is enabled so I've got root access to ChromeOS.

The Files App is a useful GUI, but I'm looking for command line access to the same file systems. Something I can run scripts from, cd, ls, etc.

If not native to ChromeOS, then is there a mounting utility that could be used in ChromeOS for command-line access? I realize there are several options such as google-drive-ocamlfuse, prasmussen/gdrive, skicka, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when they say "look in fuse", they mean look in /media/fuse to get the drive id

```
cd /media/fuse/
```

this should return "drivefs-(the drive ID)"
then from there you can do

```
cd /media/fuse/(the drivefs-(ID) that was in /media/fuse/)/root
```

this should work, it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

To access g-drive from from crosh terminal (you'll have to look in fuse first to get the drive id)

```
cd /media/fuse/drivefs-SOMEDRIVEID/root
```

If you use the Linux integration (crostini) you can also access this from the crosh shell via:

```
cd /media/fuse/crostini_SOMEDRIVEID
```

Comment: cd /media   ERROR: unknown command: cd

Comment: How does one "look in fuse first"?